# startActivityForResult: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android

I have two projects: *ProjectA* and *ProjectB*. I am trying now to open the activity *B_Activity* from *ProjectB* inside my *ProjectA* with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.orr.con.projectb");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

but I get the following Error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

Manifest of A_Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.or.test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".A_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Manifest of B_Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.orr.con.projectb">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".B_Activity" android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

First I install *ProjectB* on the device, then *ProjectA*.
I have read through most of the related questions but i can't figure out whats my problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use implicit intent to open external app. For example:

```
    <activity android:name=".B_Activity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.orr.con.projectb.SOME_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And in first app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.orr.con.projectb.SOME_ACTION");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I also needed to add: <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> but it helped ty